# jQuery How to select the only child <a> of a <li> inside a class

Tags: jquery, css

I figured out how to do this in css :

```
.dl-menuwrapper li > a(:only-child)
```

But I don't manage to make this work in a jQuery selector :

```
$(document).on('click', '.dl-menuwrapper li a(:only-child)', function () {console.log('it works');});
```

I don't get what I am missing here and a little help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typed two extra parenthesis.

correct version:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dl-menuwrapper li a:only-child', function () {console.log('it works');});
```

and your css would be like this:

```
.dl-menuwrapper li > a:only-child{
 /* some styles */
}
```

Comment: the reason I had parenthesis in css is because I used double selector : :not(:only-child) and then I forgot to remove them

Comment: yeah, it takes time to get use to it

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `()` around `:only-child`. Remove it like following.

**CSS**

```
.dl-menuwrapper li > a:only-child
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.dl-menuwrapper li a:only-child', function () {
    console.log('it works');
});
```